# My modal is not showing when I add the id in the url

Tags: php, modal-dialog

This is the button to call the modal.

```
<a href="#ViewApplicantModal?id=<?php echo $row['applicant_code']?>" 
class="btn btn-sm" data-toggle="modal" title="View" style="background-color: 
rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.2); border-radius: 3px; color: white; border: none;"> <span  
class="glyphicon glyphicon-file"> </span></a>
```

This is the modal

```
<div class="modal fade" id="#ViewApplicantModal?id=<?php echo 
$row['applicant_code']?>">
</div>
```

When I removed the php code in the url, it works. Is there any way to get the ID from other page? THANKS FOR THE HELP!

Comment: Kindly explain more

Comment: Have you verified if the output is as expected (Ctrl+Shift+I on many browsers) ? You should end your PHP lines with a `;`.

Comment: Any reason for using "#" in you id tag of your DIV? and are you 100% sure that $row['applicant_code'] contains data?

Comment: @AymDev That doesn't the problem. semicolons are used for separating two statements. There is only one statement there

Comment: What should `#ViewApplicantModal?id=<?php echo $row['applicant_code']?>` even do? Have you tried using `#ViewApplicantModal_<?php echo $row['applicant_code']?>`?

Comment: Guys! Thank you for the help. So here's what I'm trying to do. I want that modal to  contain a specific ID.